# Jest mock Axios default request call

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs

I'm trying to mock my axios request call, but keep failing or jest will stuck.

```
import axios from 'axios';

function getToken(id) {
  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 8000,
    url: 'https://sample.com',
    headers: { profileId:id ) },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error',error)
    });
}
```

Test file

```
import axios from 'axios';

describe('Test authenticate ', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('Test getToken return with token', async () => {
    jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data:'fakeToken' } })));
    await expect(getToken('123345')).resolves.toBe('fakeToken');
  })
})
```

Here's the error I got  `message: 'Network Error'` It looks like it send out a request, instead of using the mock return

Also try:

```
jest.mock('axios');
 axios.mockReturnValue({
    data: 'fakeToken' ,
 });
```

I got this error message in the terminal:  `TypeError: (0 , _axios.default)(...).then is not a function`

And when I use  `axios.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'fakeToken' });` when I run `npm test` would stuck and no test result return

Thanks for the help!